# Background overlay cropped when scrolling on Safari iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

Has anyone come across this before? When browsing on mobile, I've set the website navigation position to fixed with `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh`

When scrolling on Chrome and Safari on iOS, the bottom of the navigation is cropped off:

[image: a]

The workaround I've come up with is to remove the background colour from the navigation and instead make the body background-color blue and make it's content semi-opaque.

```
body > *:not(#main-nav) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This solution works, but I would rather find a way of using an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, and ended up finding that this fixed it:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
```